# Utilize ng-include with raw (or compiled) HTML versus a template URL?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive, browserify

Say I've got a template that contains an element with an `ng-include` directive:

```
<div ng-include src="'templates/top-promo-content.html'"></div>
```

I'm attempting to streamline all of our templates into our built app JS (using `browserify` and the `brfs` transform), which, conceptually, would look like:

```
<div ng-include src="fs.readFileSync('./templates/top-promo-content.html', 'utf8')"></div>
```

Which would ultimately result in:

```
<div ng-include src="<ul><li>list item</li></ul>"></div>
```

Is there any way to, rather than use a template URL within an `ng-include`, utilize raw or compiled HTML instead? If not, is there another alternative in angular that would allow me to accomplish this, either as some sort of include or partial, but with the ability to include raw/compiled HTML?

Answer (score 6):

I spent a couple days on this myself and found a great solution using `$templateCache`.

**javascript**

```
app.run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
    //Add ng-include templates to template cache
    $templateCache.put('foo.html', require('./templates/foo.html'));
    $templateCache.put('bar.html', require('./templates/bar.html'));
}]);
```

**html**

```
<ng-include="'foo.html'"></ng-include>
```

This will include the templates in your *bundle.js*.

In addition if you are running `watchify` to rebundle; any changes to the template will cause watchify to fire off a rebundle and kick a live refresh with the new template.

Comment: What do you have exactly in 'foo.html' ? If I put HTML code like "<div></div>", Browserify fails with the following error: ">> Error: Line 1: Unexpected token <". Looks like it really expect javascript code there.

Comment: Never mind I found a solution and added it as a possible answer. Thanks for the pointer though!

Comment: @neric foo.html is straight html.  You do not use module.export

Answer (score 2):

Templates can be included on a page with the `script` tag.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templates/top-promo-content.html">
  <ul><li>list item</li></ul>
</script>
```

This puts the template into the template cache and the `ng-include` directive gets it from there. The same is true for every directive that gets templates via a URL.

Comment: I don't know that this solves my problem; I'm attempting to streamline templates into the build using require statements via browserify. Putting the template directly in the parent template as HTML surrounded by script tags doesn't allow me to do so. I'm hoping to streamline the HTML directly into the template include/placeholder, versus using an include or continuing to add templates to angular's template cache. I'll add another example to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I have adapted Malkus answer to make it work in my case:

**Javascript:**

```
app.run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
    //Add ng-include templates to template cache
    $templateCache.put('foo.html', fs.readFileSync('/templates/foot.html').toString());
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<ng-include="'foo.html'"></ng-include>
```

Works great!